# Compare current time with a specific time in a if statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, time

I'm trying to compare the current time with a specific time in React Native by using JavaScript but it's not working with this method that i have tried.
This is how i have tried it:

```
export default function SettingsComponent() {
  let today = new Date();
  let currentTime = today.toLocaleTimeString();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentTime)
    if(currentTime == "12:39:30"){
      console.log('Comparison is working')
    }
  })
}
```

If there are any other suggestions to do this, let me know!

Comment: What does `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` show when you run it in your browser console?

Comment: Comparing a [language-sensitive representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) of a time to a fixed format like `"12:39:30"` might not be solid. I would rather use `getHours` and `getMinutes` to compare and ignore the seconds. Does your `console.log` actually show that format?

Comment: Best if you can compare by timestamp, which is the number of milliseconds past Jan 1, 1970 GMT. Doing this lets you ignore "annoying things" like time zones

Comment: When i console.log the currentTime variabel, it shows the time in this format: 12:39:30

Comment: Exactly, you should also use a tolerance, or the component has to mount in the exact second you're testing against.

Comment: @ControlAltDel hitting the website on that exact millisecond is like winning the lottery.

Comment: @JavaScript which is why you should use a timestamp. Doing comparisons by timestamp you can do `if (Math.abs(b-a) < (1000 * 60 * 3) /* 3 minutes */ ) { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work by passing argument(s) to [`toLocalTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) so to guarantee the format you get from it. For instance, you could specify a locale that uses the hh:mm:ss format:

```
today.toLocaleTimeString("en-SE")
```

Secondly, you should realise that you only have 1 second to have a match. One can imagine how some latency can make you miss a match, and the code only gets executed just after that second passed.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your useEffect is running before the currentTime is set.  Try adding the currentTime to the useEffects dependency array.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(currentTime)
        if(currentTime == "12:39:30"){
          console.log('Comparison is working')
        }
      }, [currentTime])
```